# Laravel - displaying variable

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem. I use external library to laravel 5.2 to display weather for airport and I have problem with displaying it in blade.

My controller:

```
public function showMetar() {
    $egss = new Metar('EGSS');
    $metar = sprintf('The METAR report for Stansted (EGSS) is: %s', $egss);
    return view('home', compact('metar'));
}
```

And I try to display it in blade using `{{ $metar }}` and it display me undefined variable `metar`... Don't know really how to define it to display it in my home.blade

Comment: Can you display the whole error?

Answer (score 1):

Try a `dd($metar);` before before you return the view, that's a nice way to check if a variable actually is what it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the $metar-valiable is not null or empty. Please note that compact() will *not* issue a warning if the specified variable name is undefined. Therefore I always use this instead:

```
view('home', ['metar' => $metar]);
```

Comment: Have you checked $metar before you pass it on to the view?

Comment: That is true about compact, however, even if `$metar` was null it still shouldn't throw and exception and according to the example it is definitely defined in the controller.

Comment: its taken from this https://packagist.org/packages/ballen/metar and i try to integrate it with laravel